# Getting required rows in mysql using GROUPBY

Tags: mysql, group-by

I have a table named travel which is as follows:

```
+-------+-----+----------+
| Name  | Day | Distance |
+-------+-----+----------+
| Ravi  | 1   | 10       |
| Ravi  | 2   | 21       |
| Ravi  | 3   | 23       |
| Hari  | 1   | 12       |
| Hari  | 2   | 32       |
| Kiran | 1   | 12       |
| Kiran | 2   | 32       |
| Kiran | 3   | 21       |
| Kiran | 4   | 43       |
+-------+-----+----------+
```

using group in sql for this table as

```
select name, day, distance, sum(distance) as total_dist 
from travel
group by name;
```

I get the result as follows

```
+-------+-----+----------+------------+
| Name  | Day | Distance | total_dist |
+-------+-----+----------+------------+
| Ravi  | 1   | 10       | 54         |
| Hari  | 1   | 12       | 44         |
| Kiran | 1   | 12       | 108        |
+-------+-----+----------+------------+
```

That is mysql gives the top row by default for columns which are not aggregated. But I would prefer to get all the rows with aggregated values or rows with bottom row in the group like as follows:

```
+-------+-----+----------+------------+
| Name  | Day | Distance | total_dist |
+-------+-----+----------+------------+
| Ravi  | 3   | 23       | 54         |
| Hari  | 2   | 32       | 44         |
| Kiran | 4   | 43       | 108        |
+-------+-----+----------+------------+
```

or either in this way:

```
+-------+-----+----------+------------+
| Name  | Day | Distance | total_dist |
+-------+-----+----------+------------+
| Ravi  | 1   | 10       | 54         |
| Ravi  | 2   | 21       | 54         |
| Ravi  | 3   | 23       | 54         |
| Hari  | 1   | 12       | 44         |
| Hari  | 2   | 32       | 44         |
| Kiran | 1   | 12       | 108        |
| Kiran | 2   | 32       | 108        |
| Kiran | 3   | 21       | 108        |
| Kiran | 4   | 43       | 108        |
+-------+-----+----------+------------+
```

I am new to using mysql and confused with using group by, please guide me if any of the above two results are possible to get.

Comment: Both are possible -- which do you actually need?

Comment: Can I get both of them, it would help me understanding group by better

Comment: *"That is mysql gives the top row by default for columns which are not aggregated."* -- that't not true. Your query is not valid `SQL` and it shouldn't run. `MySQL` is kind, ignores the errors (columns that do not appear in `GROUP BY` should be aggregated) and generates a record set. But it picks some random value from the column. The result is indeterminate. If you export the table data and import it into a different database, the results set generated by the same query may be different. Read here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-handling.html

Comment: Thank you for information, sorry for generalizing things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the entire list with the `sum` for each group, you can use a subquery and `join` the total back to the original table:

```
select t.name, t.day, t.distance, t2.total_dist
from travel t
  join (select name, sum(distance) total_dist
        from travel
        group by name) t2 on t.name = t2.name
```

- [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3844e/1)

---

Or to get the `max` day per group, just include `max(day)` in the subquery:

```
select t.name, t.day, t.distance, t2.total_dist
from travel t
  join (select name, sum(distance) total_dist, max(day) max_day
        from travel
        group by name) t2 on t.name = t2.name and t.day = t2.max_day
```

- [More Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3844e/2)

Comment: That works perfect. But I have a small doubt in second query. It works perfect but  a small change in question. Can I still get a result like in second query, if have some column say isFinalDay which says y or n as its values instead of day 1,2,3 and so on as used here.

Answer (score 0):

it will work for you

```
select name,max(day),max(distance)
from tablename
group by name
```

and other case

```
select name,max(day),max(distance),(select sum(distance) from table) as total_dist
from tablename
group by name
```